# How to launch FB app from URL (specifically the share function)

Tags: facebook

I'm looking for a way to replicate this:

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.buildfire.com

But I want to force it to use the Facebook App - I know that you can launch the FB app using this command

```
fb://
```

but have not been able to recreate the sharer function.

Any ideas?  I can share in WhatsApp using

```
whatsapp://send?text=Check%20out%20this%20site%20http://buildfire.com/
```

Note: This is for mobile devices only that is why I want to force it to use the FB app

Answer (score 0):

Direct deep-linking into the Facebook App, or better, into a specific section of the app (Share Dialog, User Profile etc.) using the Custom URL Scheme of the Facebook iOS app is not officially supported.

You can however add the `FBSDKShareKit` framework to your app and open a Share Dialog that way, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios#share_dialog